# How to fix the relationship problem of "Property [id] does not exist" problem

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three model 1. Task.php 2. Project.php 3. User.php.
Task have a one to many relationship with user and project.php.

Task.php

```
 public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'member_id');
    }
```

User.php

```
public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
```

Project.php

```
public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
```

Nowi want to retrieve all the task that is associated with users where project id is one (Actually not one, id is passed through url).Here is my attempt

```
public function taskList($id)
    {
        $project=Project::with('tasks')->find($id);
        $tasks=Task::has('user')->whereHas('project',function($project){
            $project->where('id',$project->id);
        })->get();
        dd($tasks);
        return view('leader.tasks',compact('project'));
    }
```

In the above either i give the $id which is i get from the url either $project->id, it always through me the error.Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
public function taskList($id)
    {
        $project=Project::with('tasks')->find($id);
        $tasks=Task::has('user')->whereHas('project', function($query) use ($project) {
            $query->where('id', $project->id);
        })->get();
        dd($tasks);
        return view('leader.tasks',compact('project'));
    }
```

Comment: yes it solves the error but still it cannot retrieve the names of user

Comment: oh nope i mistakes somewhere, it solves my problem...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `with()` method along with `has()`

```
public function taskList($id)
{
    $project=Project::with('tasks')->find($id);
    $tasks=Task::with('user')->has('user')->whereHas('project', function($query) use ($project) {
        $query->where('id', $project->id);
    })->get();
    dd($tasks);
    return view('leader.tasks',compact('project'));
}
```